# How to bind ListBox to a very large data set

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, listbox, large-data

I want to display a very large number of items to my `ListBox`. So I use binding like this

```
listBox.ItemsSource = largeList;
```

My `ListBox` does use `VirtualizingStackPanel`, however, I see that it takes very long time to render on the screen.

Is there a more effective way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there are realy big data you should display them to user

By the way you could trick it like this :
Make a new timer , on tick event (every 5ms) add less than 5 items

Comment: I have a very large number of record that I want to bind to ListBox, and it's really slow when I bind

Comment: i am not sure about binding's speed , i would use it like this :

`    MyListbox.items.add(Myitem)    `

Comment: Timer is not that helpful ?